# How can I prevent an unknown ID field from showing in FastAPI documentation when using Pydantic models for validation?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

The problem is that when using FastAPI with Pydantic models for request body validation, the model's fields are automatically included in the generated Swagger UI or ReDoc documentation.

This can be useful for users to know what fields are required for a request, but it can also be confusing when a field like id is included in the model but is not actually required or known by the user at the time of the request. In addition the if the user does provide it, it shouldn't be used by the system.

In this scenario, the id field is assigned by the database upon creation of the item, so it is not known by the user when they make the request. However, since the id field is included in the Pydantic model, it is also included in the documentation, which can be confusing for users.

The goal is to remove the id field from the documentation while still keeping it in the Pydantic model for validation purposes.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


# I don't want the user to submit an id here as its not user defined.
@app.post("/item/create", status_code=201, tags=["Item"])
def create_item(item: Item) -> Item:
    
    # create item in database and get item id
    ........
    
    # return the created item with the id included
    return created_item
```

One option could be to change the item model as follows:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int | None = None
    name: str
```

However this solution doesn't seem like the best one to me for a number of reasons.

Another option was to create two seperate Item models, one without the ID field and one with it. But this also seems like the wrong way to solve this problem.

Appreciate your advice.

Comment: You can define two models, but use inheritance to avoid duplication: define one model that does not include the `id`, and one that *inherits from the first* and just adds the `id` field.

Comment: Thank you, whilst this does work, when you view the documentation the 'id' will be added at the very end (from my testing) which doesn't seem like the best solution either unfortunately. This data should ideally come at the beginning.

Comment: I heard this argument so many times already about the `id` field coming at the end. I still don't get it. Is it purely an aesthetics thing? Because JSON objects are **unordered** so it is completely irrelevant in what order the keys appear in the documentation.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I suppose its just because it seems to be very uncommon to see an id field coming in at the end.

I seem to have resolved the issue with inheritance by creating a class that holds the id, and a class that holds the other components (name, etc). Then using inheritance:

class ItemWithId(_ItemBase, _ItemId):
    pass


class ItemWithoutId(_ItemBase):
    pass

The order of the inheritance is important here: (_ItemBase, _ItemId) to ensure the id displays at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way, however this is the solution I came up with.

```
class _ItemId(BaseModel):
    _id: int
```

```
class _ItemBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: int
    description: str
```

The below order of inheritance is important to make sure the id is first.

```
class ItemWithId(_ItemBase, _ItemId):
    pass
```

```
class ItemWithoutId(_ItemBase):
    pass
```